# Xcode 9 issue duplication ('Uncategorized' + i.e. 'Swift Compiler Error')

Tags: swift, xcode, xcode9

For reason unknown to me, Xcode 9 started to duplicate some (most) of the issues (errors and warnings both). It adds 'Uncategorized' group in the Issue navigator and also displays each of them twice in the code.

[image]

[image]

Not like it's critical, but uncomfortable.

The question is, have I unknowingly turned this on somewhere or is this a default behaviour for Xcode 9?

I'm using Xcode 9.1 + Swift 4 currently, but it happened also with Xcode 9 + Swift 3.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug with the current release of Xcode. A temporary fix for this issue is deleting the Derived Data folder.

Comment: That in facts helps for the first build only, in my case ) Well, then we wait.